# Atomineer Utils VB.NET XML Comment Documentation Not Working

Tags: vb.net, xml-comments, xml-documentation, atomineer

I just downloaded the trial for this application and it doesn't seem to work. I went through the Quick Setup guide and it all looked great. Now when I place my cursor on a member of any type and press Ctrl+Shift+D it does nothing. I placed it on top, inside, etc... Nothing. If I press Ctrl+Shift+A (twice) on top of the member it tells me to place it "in the line of the form MyType myVariable;". I'm not quite sure what this means unless it's referring to C# but this project is VB.NET which it doesn't seem to recognize. Anyone else have this issue? I was hoping it would make things easier since I've read that it can document an entire document rather than having to member by member.

Using VS 2010 Premium.

Answer (score 0):

Drop me an email to support (at) atomineerutils.com with a bit of example code that exhibits the problem, and I'll help you sort it out.

---

**(edit)**

Please note that AtomineerUtils only officially supports VB 9 onwards, although where the syntax of earlier versions is compatible (i.e. in most cases), it will still work perfectly well.

I've now investigated this, and I can't repeat the documentation behaviour you have mentioned - it works as expected for me. (However, I did find and fix a regression introduced to the Visual Basic handling in a recent version - a small coding glitch that meant some methods could be incorrectly documented as constructors, so thanks for indirectly helping me find this issue!)

All I can suggest is that if you see a problem in any application, the best (and often only) way to get it fixed is to let the author know!

Comment: Ok so this is what I do. Say I'm trying to document a VB Method. I put my cursor on the first line of the method. Ctrl+Shift+D does nothing, but if I press Ctrl+Shift+A (twice mind you) it comes up with this error "AddAccessMethods failed - Member variables must have a lowercase intitial character, or a prefix/suffix that will distinguish them from the Property/Accessor". I get this error no matter what I try to document.

Comment: I think this was just me. I press Ctrl+Shift+A, then while still holding Ctrl+Shift I press D and it seems to work now. Guess I just misunderstood how it worked. All I need to figure out now is how to add particular xml tags like <seealso>, etc...